# Why I can't cout the int in class

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

class machine
{
public:
    machine(int a, int b)
    {
         int some_int = a;
         int model = b;     
    }
    void info()
    {
        std::cout << model;
    }
};

int main()
{
    machine BMW(12, 1998);
    BMW.info();
}
```

I don't know why I get an error when run the C++ code.I can't `cout` the model in `void info()`.

Comment: You should clarify what error you get. At a glance, I would say it's because you haven't declared `model` a member of `machine`. You should refer to your learning material about classes

Comment: You've declared the "ints" as variables within the body of the constructor, so they cease to exist when the constructor completes.   They need to be members of the class   i.e.   outside the body of the constructor.   In the constructor, a different syntax is needed to then initialise them.     If you want more specifics, read the section on classes in any basic/introductory C++ text - you'll learn more that way, than you would if someone simply fixed your code.

Comment: Please don't post on stackoverflow that you get an error yet not show exactly what the error is. Thinking like a programmer means a good analysis of what the problem is.

Comment: It's a matter of ***scope***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model variable you have declared has it's scope only inside the constructor method. So, it won't persist for the lifetime of the object. To make the info variable be an attribute of the object, you have to keep it outside all functions of that class.

```
#include <iostream>

class machine
{
int model;
public:
    machine(int a, int b)
    {
         int some_int = a;
         model = b;     
    }
    void info()
    {
        std::cout << model;
    }
};

int main()
{
    machine BMW(12, 1998);
    BMW.info();
}
```

Here the `some_int` would only be available inside the constructor. But the `info` variable is an instance variable and is available for all the functions of the class.

Comment: it should be private?(model)

Comment: If you don't specify anything, the variable is private.